# Maven not able to detect jsr94.jar even after this is installed in m2 folder with correct structure

Tags: java, maven

I have been trying to migrate ant build project to maven project by converting this project to maven using eclipse plugin. All is good except it is not able to detect jsr94 dependencies.

Error:

> [WARNING] The POM for jsr94:jsr94:jar:1.1 is missing, no dependency >information available
>   [WARNING] The POM for org.infinispan:infinispan-core:jar:4.2.1.FINAL is >missing, no dependency information available

What I did to correct this :

Corrected pom.xml with this entry:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>jsr94</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr94</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

Also, verified the jar is present at the proper folder within m2 folder at C:\Users\xxxx.m2\jsr94\jsr94\1.1.
Tried maven clean and then maven install. But the same error again.

I expect if m2 has got the expected jars at the correct folder structure, it should be able to pick up the jars. Please help with this or any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use `mvn install:install-file` for the `jsr94:jsr94`? or copy it manually? (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Comment: yes, using the **install:install-file -Dfile=path\jsr94-1.1.jar -DgroupId=jsr94 -DartifactId=jsr94 -Dversion=1.1 -Dpackaging=jar**  . It says Cannot install artifact. Artifact is already in the local repository. But when i try compile , then it is throwing above error

Comment: Please try to rename or remove the previous installed `jsr94:jsr94`, then execute the `mvn install:install-file` and compile again.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the lead. I solved it by deleting the jar from m2 folder and again installing it using this command:

```
install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\Desktop\jsr94-1.1.jar -DgroupId=jsr94 -DartifactId=jsr94 -Dversion=1.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Thereafter, the build is successful.